# How to implement X-XSRF-TOKEN with angular2 app and net core app?

Tags: c#, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I have my net core app and antiforgery middlweare set up in Startup.cs:

```
        services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
```

in ConfigureServices method, and

```
        app.UseAntiForgeryMiddleware();
```

in Configure method.

Antiforgery middleware:

```
public class AntiForgeryMiddleware
    {
        private readonly IAntiforgery antiforgery;
        private readonly AntiforgeryOptions options;
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public AntiForgeryMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery, IOptions<AntiforgeryOptions> options)
        {
            this.next = next;
            this.antiforgery = antiforgery;
            this.options = options.Value;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                if (string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
                    string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/index.html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // We can send the request token as a JavaScript-readable cookie, and Angular will use it by default.
                    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
                }

                if (string.Equals("POST", context.Request.Method, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    await antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(context);

                    context.Response.StatusCode = 204;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
```

I use

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

on my controller action.

How do I set up angular2 post request to send x-xsrf-token header which will match net core app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about is inserting header `x-xsrf-token` into your request and send it to the backend.

You can accomplish that with modifying header options when you make http call:

**Service**

```
@Injectable
export class YourService {

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    makeSomeRequst(data: any) {

        let headers = new Headers({ 'X-XSRF-TOKEN': yourTokenFromLocalStorage });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.post('url to your API call', data, options)
            .subscribe(result => {
                console.log('Your request was done and compliant to security on backend');
            }, err => {
                console.error('There was a problem with authentication');
                console.log(err)
            });
    }

}
```

With this, you will modify header and insert token to comply with your security mechanism. If you want to make that automated, you can follow this tutorial on how to create interceptor for http calls and insert token for all of them in one place, not to do it manually in every service:

You need to extend Angular's Http and provide new dependenices into your module.
Follow the full tutorial here:

https://medium.com/aviabird/http-interceptor-angular2-way-e57dc2842462

Comment: Mario thanks, how do you store token in the first place "yourTokenFromLocalStorage" and when to be identical to the one that net core app generates? Is there any way of how antiforgery token flow in this case should work?

Comment: Well, you can save token or any data in the frontend(browser) ´localStorage´ by using browser API for that. It is based on set/get by key. localStorage.setItem('token', tokenValue). To get it use localStorage.getItem('token'). As for the token from backend. You can take it from authentication response from your backend and save it in localStorage and use it later for further cases.

Comment: that's what i needed, hvala

Comment: Glad i helped. Nema na cemu :)

Comment: Mario do you have an idea how to use XSRFStrategy in this case?

Comment: Well i haven't worked with C#, but i assume that you can use standard architecture with REST full API. You sign in, server does checking of username/passoword, generates x-xsrf-token and saves it for your user in the DB. You get that generated token and store it on the frontend and use it every time you make some call. When logging out delete token from the DB, and any attempt to use that token will result 401 (unauthorized) requesst. See some resources regarding that: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/

Answer (score 2):

**Thanks to the CookieXSRFStrategy provided by Angular, Angular does that part for you.**

*In the case of Angular, you will be using their $http service for sending AJAX requests. This service will automatically include a header with the name X-XSRF-TOKEN if it can find the token value as a cookie with the name XSRF-TOKEN.*

At the .net end you just have to create some middleware that will get the request token, and store its value as the XSRF-TOKEN cookie (`HttpOnly = false`).

**Validation Process:-**

1) The application will send back to the browser a cookie XSRF-TOKEN with the request token and another cookie .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.* with the cookie token.

2) Whenever Angular sends an Ajax request, the request will include a header X-XSRF-TOKEN with the request token and the cookie .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.* with the cookie token.

3) The Antiforgery validation will make sure that both tokens are valid and share the same secret, etc.

Since the default header name for the request token is `RequestVerificationToken`, we need to change it and make sure Antiforgery searches for the request token in a header with name X-XSRF-TOKEN. Let’s just manually add Antiforgery and setup the options in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(opts => opts.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-Token");
```

Now we need to make sure we generate the tokens and include the request token in a cookie with name XSRF-TOKEN so Angular $http service can read it and include it as the header.

This cannot be an http only cookie, since Angular code needs to read the cookie value so it can be included as a header in subsequent requests!