# Regenerating AntiForgeryToken for form after ajax call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-2.0, antiforgerytoken

Following [asp-net core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-2.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas%20%22asp.net%20core%20docs) I successfully call my actions using ajax and add the antiforgery token as a header.

Now I want to make this validation "per request". The ajax call is not refreshing the form and the validation token it's the same for all subsequent requests. Which works ok but does not satisfy my security requirements.

I would like to attach to my response a new token, update the form and be sure that once I used a token that is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a new AntiForgeryToken do the following:

```
 //inject IAntiforgery antiforgery into your class

 var antiforgeryTokenSet = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext);
```

Then also from your backend code return `antiforgeryTokenSet.RequestToken` to the client code so that it now has access to the new Request Token.  Note the call to `GetAndStoreTokens` will return the new cookie portion of the antiforgery TokenSet as part of the response.  So when the client code sends back the RequestToken in it's next request both parts of the TokenSet will be present and the TokenSet will validate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call below code on every request:-

```
var token = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext);
        context.Response.Cookies.Append(requestTokenCookieName, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
                        {
                            HttpOnly = false, 
                            Secure = true
                        });
```

It will create new token and will add it to the response. But calling above code on every request is not all that beneficial.

Please see the below link for more detail on Antiforgery:-
[How to implement X-XSRF-TOKEN with angular2 app and net core app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312973/how-to-implement-x-xsrf-token-with-angular2-app-and-net-core-app/53755131#53755131)